# How do I convert a concrete, statically dispatched `T: Trait` to a dynamically dispatched `dyn Trait`?

Tags: rust, observer-pattern

In this code, I have the skeleton of an observable system. The documentation on implementing Observable and other decoupling patterns are usually missing a final step on allowing access to the listener while also having it be `&mut` during the notification call, but that's what `RefCell` is intended to handle. So I have this code all worked out, but I'm having a last piece of trouble getting my concrete `T` into the `&dyn Trait`.

```rust
use std::{cell::RefCell, rc::Rc};

pub trait Observer {
    fn notify(&mut self);
}

#[derive(Default)]
pub struct Subject<'s> {
    listeners: Vec<Rc<RefCell<Box<dyn Observer + 's>>>>,
}

pub fn wrap<T>(t: T) -> Rc<RefCell<Box<T>>> {
    Rc::new(RefCell::new(Box::new(t)))
}

impl<'s> Subject<'s> {
    pub fn add_observer(&mut self, observer: Rc<RefCell<Box<dyn Observer + 's>>>) {
        self.listeners.push(observer)
    }

    pub fn notify(&mut self) {
        for listener in &mut self.listeners {
            listener.borrow_mut().notify();
        }
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    use super::{wrap, Observer, Subject};

    #[derive(Default)]
    pub struct Counter {
        count: usize,
    }

    impl Observer for Counter {
        fn notify(&mut self) {
            self.count += 1;
        }
    }

    #[test]
    fn it_observes() {
        let mut subject = Subject::default();
        let counter = wrap(Counter::default());

        subject.add_observer(counter); // mismatched types

        for i in 1..5 {
            subject.notify();
            subject.notify();

            assert_eq!(counter.borrow().count, i * 2);
        }
    }
}
```

The full error is

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/observer.rs:48:30
   |
48 |         subject.add_observer(counter);
   |                              ^^^^^^^ expected trait object `dyn Observer`, found struct `Counter`
   |
   = note: expected struct `Rc<RefCell<Box<(dyn Observer + 'static)>>>`
              found struct `Rc<RefCell<Box<Counter>>>
```

I've seen (what looks like) this pattern used in a number of contexts, but I can't tell what either I'm missing or doing differently.

How do I get the `T: Trait` out of its static dispatch and into dynamic dispatch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take to boxing outside of your `wrap` function, and box the counter itself with the proper box type:

```rust
pub fn wrap<T>(t: T) -> Rc<RefCell<T>> {
    Rc::new(RefCell::new(t))
}
...
let counter: Box<dyn Observer> = Box::new(Counter::default());
let counter = wrap(counter);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=78b8c316d04696095f48f05a9c1e783f)

Btw, once you have the dynamic dispatch, you have an `dyn Observer` so you lose access to the `Counter` itself. You will have to take ownership of it and `downcast` the pointer to the concrete type again.